# Ghostscript version doesn't change in Laradock

Tags: docker, docker-compose, laradock

I'm using [laradock](http://laradock.io/) to run my Laravel app and I'm trying to install the most up to date version of GhostScript in php-fpm dockerfile:

```
FROM laradock/php-fpm:7.0--1.2

RUN apt-get update && \
apt-get install -y \
poppler-utils \
ghostscript
```

But when I check the version it's still GPL Ghostscript 9.06 (2012-08-08)

```
docker exec project_php-fpm_1 gs -v
```

any idea why it's not getting the most up to date version?

Comment: If I helped you, please, upvote me if you don't mind :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason is that your apt-repository hasn't last image.
You could add a newer repository and then update, but maybe most recent repository doesn't still have lastest although a newer than you have.

I'm affraid that the only way to have latest is check in **Ghostscript** web page last and do a "manual installation" in Dockerfile:

```
FROM laradock/php-fpm:7.0--1.2

RUN apt-get update && \
apt-get install -y \
poppler-utils 
RUN wget https://github.com/ArtifexSoftware/ghostpdl-downloads/releases/download/gs923/ghostscript-9.23-linux-x86_64.tgz
RUN tar zxvf ghostscript-9.23-linux-x86_64.tgz && \
  cd ghostscript-9.23-linux-x86_64 && \
  make && make install <-- or whatever you need to install it
```